# As a UX designer how should i best portray my portfolio, to get projects for hard core UX designer and not an all rounder UI/UX guy

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, portfolio, project

Are Dribbble and Behance the only best options, my field of interest is more of UX(logic, flow, concept, wireframing) and comparatively less as UI(icons, fonts, colors).

Are the UI and UX strongly married couple, which needs to be skilled together in order to be a great UX designer.

I know it is important to have a background as a Visual designer and also understand responsiveness and frontend code till some point but what in case to have a specialization in UX, considering it as a niche and gaining expertise in UX methodologies specific.

I have had a background of graphic, html, css and a bit of HPL's, so what should i do to narrow myself as an expert in UX and also get the work in-spite being not too old in field of UX as most clients are looking for an allrounder UI/UX designer, specially when I have experience of 2 years in UX field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't pose a UX question.  Even though a portfolio is a part of a UX professional's work, it doesn't fall under the topic of UX.

Comment: People who work as UX strategists might consider their skill set (which includes a broad knowledge of different aspects of the UX design work) to be a specialist area even though they don't necessarily go into the same level of depth as other UX specialists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation for your portfolio is to show the kind of work that you want to do.  No point in using Dribbble or Behance if you're interested in logic and flows - these are great for presenting visual design, but not so much the work behind it.

While you've got all that experience, that sounds to me like it's great for a CV / personal website - but your portfolio should reflect the kind of work that you want to do.

I've also found that less is more.  In my most recent folio, I've got literally one project in there - but I talk about all the stages from the start to finish and focus on my methods and how they are applied, as opposed to showing a website that just looks great on the surface.

Every job has a different definition of UX or UI, and they all have different titles too.  The best you can do is showcase the work that you like doing, and let people label it how they want.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I got your point. Showing the work what i expect the client  to hire me for is a great suggestion. I would stick to that.
I appreciate you put time to answer my question. thanks again

Comment: @Vincent Feeney..Liked the comment where you mentioned about only project but in detail. Many people think that there needs to be many number of projects done before Portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

UX and UI are usually misread and confused in many fields. UX Design refers to the term user experience design, while UI Design "its compliment, the look and feel of the application/products".Both elements are crucial to a product and work closely together.Where UX Design is a more analytical and technical field, UI Design is closer to what we refer to as graphic design, though the responsibilities are somewhat more complex.

To be a UX Designer,  Fred Beecher highlighted few traits which are : 
Passion for the craft.

- Curiosity about people and technology.
- Ability to learn quickly.
- A detail-oriented nature.
- Receptiveness to feedback (willingness to accept constructive    criticism and act on
  it).

UX has no need to coding but UI is.However, Programming skills will make you stand out when you build a strong portfolio in UX field and definitely you will be favored by both employers and customers.

Online Courses: honestly I have seen very few good/great online courses that really teach you how to conduct a proper research,empathize with users, create a usable personas and user scenarios. The best of them all are by Susan Weinschenk online course " She has made an excellent and comprehensive course" [Check it out](https://www.theteamw.com/). Also, you can read her book "100 things every designer needs to know about people".

Additionally, you can check Alan Cooper courses, he is widely known as the father of Visual. He is the creator of personas, if i am not mistaken.

Last but not least, you can read the following books:

- Design of everything by Steve Krug
- Don't make me think  by Donald Norman
- Letting Go of the Words by Ginny Redish

Comment: Thanks Serag for provided great collection of sources, I would go through them. It was very helpful of you to sum up the best books for gaining more clarity over the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Present your work as case studies.

Employers will assume that you have worked as a part of a team so any work you present will need to be accompanied with a detailed description of your part in producing it.

You could present some screenshots of a beautiful mobile app but your potential employer will ask themselves "What bit did they do? - are they a graphic/UI designer? are they hybrid? are they pure UX? did they create the flow? did they make wireframes?...

If, however, you present the same screenshots of your beautiful app and write up your personal part in bringing it to life ("I researched users and created personas that I then used to create a user journey and wireframes before handing off to the UI team" - obviously with much more detail than that!) then your potential employer has a much stronger idea of what you're capable of how you might fit into their process.

It also helps if you have images of each of the steps that you took (could be snapshots from your phone of workshops, moodboards, sketches, etc)

If you are using research as a part of your portfolio don't forget to explain your methodologies!